# Информация об фрагменте с активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Есть программа  с единственным активити на котором при нажатии кнопки может меняться (использую замену через трансакцию) фрагмент!

Действия которые будут выполнять другие кнопки зависят от того какой фрагмент сейчас на активности.

**Как можно узнать какой фрагмент сейчас на активности?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от Вашей реализации. Некоторые из вариантов:

1. Создать переменную, в которой Вы будете запоминать какой фрагмент прикрепляете. В зависимости от сохраненного значения дифференциировать действия.
2. При добавлении фрагмента указывать тег и затем по тегу также дифференциировать действия.

Comment: а можно каким-то способом отслеживать изменения на  активности ?  Не события нажатия, а изменения, например, контента

Comment: @Vitaliy, зависит от контента. Многие стандартные вещи можно отследить `listener`ами, для своих элементов можно сделать свою реализацию.